# Python: Accessing List of Dict. Typeerror: Column name can't be str

Tags: python

I have a question about accessing a list of dict in Python. I'm trying to access all value in a column of a CSV file. I've isolated and simplified the problem into the code below.

I'm trying to define a function which

inputs:
1) data set (list of dict)
2) column name

outputs: 1) printed list of all value in column

Instead i receive a "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

```
dict_1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
dict_2 = {'a':4, 'b':5, 'c':6}
list_1 = [dict_1, dict_2]

def len_unique_element(data_set,column_name):

    data = ([data_set[column_name] for row in data_set])

    return print (data)

len_unique_element (list_1, 'a')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `data_set` with `row` in the list comprehension. The `data_set` is a `list` and `row` is a `dict` in the `data_set`.

```
data = [row[column_name] for row in data_set]
```

You should use `return` or `print` instead of combine them.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for column_name in data_set when you should be looking in row.

```
def len_unique_element(data_set, column_name):
    return [row[column_name] for row in data_set]
```